# how to align the text that a textview shows to the left ? in android app in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, android-xml, android-scrollview

i have a textview inside of a scrollview...in a linearlayout :
when i open the avd to test the app the firs line of the text I'm getting is aligned to the right, and the rest of the paragraph is normal(starting from left).thats with every single paragraph.

this is what i  have :

```
<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="360dp"
android:addStatesFromChildren="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="60dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

                  <!-- Description Label -->

</ScrollView>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried <android:gravity="left"> ?

Comment: @darry.ten i already tried :

Comment: <android:gravity="left">

Comment: and also i already tried :
<android:layout_gravity="left">

Comment: @darryn.ten i already fixed it...it wasnt about the code ..it was about the way i write the text on my TextView on the xml file(inside of the description tag) .. it had to write the text all the way to the left( to the first column).thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wasnt about the code ..it was about the way i write the text on my TextView on the xml file(inside of the description tag) .. it had to write the text all the way to the left( to the first column).